# Where can I find daily UK newspaper headlines online in a computer-readable format?

Tags: triggers, rss, feed, aggregation

I'd like to keep up with current affairs by scanning the newspaper headlines, and I'm not always able to walk past a newspaper stand.

Where can I find this same information online? I'm happy to do the programming work to collate them myself, but it's not clear from newspapers websites which stories are on the front page of the physical paper. Also the website headlines change during the day.

I want to keep abreast of the UK front page stories and be sure I've not missed anything. I'm imagining some kind of API, or something like IFTTT. It must be robust enough not to break when the website HTML changes.

Comment: I think this question is not a good fit for [SO] and should be closed (which is not possible now due to the bounty). It’s asking for off-site resource (probably an API) at best, or is not related to programming at all at worst. Try again elsewhere. I know [SE] has a site about opendata, maybe there this question would be on-topic.

Comment: I found a BBC blog which shows the front page of papers every day - http://bbc.co.uk/news/blogs/the_papers - not computer readable, but it's more-or-less the format I wanted to end up with :)

Comment: There's a free API over at https://newsapi.org that provides top headlines for some of the UK newspapers (including the Mirror, the Guardian, the Independent, Daily Mail, Metro, and Telegraph).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BBC News has an RSS headlines feed for the UK: http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/uk/rss.xml.

The Guardian and the BBC both have numerous other feeds; see: http://www.theguardian.com/help/feeds and http://www.bbc.com/news/10628494.

This may help as well: http://www.currybet.net/cbet_blog/2007/11/top-100-british-newspaper-feed.php

As far as what's in the physical newspaper, I don't think you'll find exactly that. If you check the feed every morning, anything that happens later in the day would be in tomorrow's paper.

You could convert the feeds to JSON (or the like) using [Yahoo Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com), and then process it how you like, or view the RSS feeds in a feedreader.

Answer (score 0):

I tried Google News RSS + feedburner, but the headlines seemed very random and not related to what I see in a browser, e.g. http://news.google.co.uk/news/feeds?output=rss